How to modify smali member variables
I'm trying to reverse engineer an apk (just to learn) and I want the program to think I'm a VIP. I think I found the main logic
method private final updateUserInfo(Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/ConsumerBean;)V
    .registers 5

    .line 1
    invoke-virtual {p0}, Ln/FK;->getBinding()Landroidx/viewbinding/ViewBinding;

    move-result-object v0

    check-cast v0, Ltop/acmb/aton/apwrxt/databinding/FragmentVipBinding;

    iget-object v0, v0, Ltop/acmb/aton/apwrxt/databinding/FragmentVipBinding;->a0qlLp:Landroid/widget/TextView;

    invoke-virtual {p1}, Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/ConsumerBean;->getNickname()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Landroid/widget/TextView;->setText(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V

    .line 2
    invoke-virtual {p1}, Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/ConsumerBean;->getMember()Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean;

    move-result-object v0

    invoke-virtual {v0}, Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean;->getConsumerMember()Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean$ConsumerMemberBean;

    move-result-object v0

    invoke-virtual {v0}, Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean$ConsumerMemberBean;->getLevel()I

    move-result v0

    invoke-virtual {p0}, Ln/FK;->getBinding()Landroidx/viewbinding/ViewBinding;

    move-result-object v1

    check-cast v1, Ltop/acmb/aton/apwrxt/databinding/FragmentVipBinding;

    iget-object v1, v1, Ltop/acmb/aton/apwrxt/databinding/FragmentVipBinding;->a0cDM:Landroid/widget/ImageView;

    invoke-static {v0, v1}, Lshop/ahhnr/dws/esqq/util/a02Bw;->a0S(ILandroid/widget/ImageView;)V

    .line 3
    invoke-virtual {p1}, Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/ConsumerBean;->getMember()Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean;

    move-result-object v0

    invoke-virtual {v0}, Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean;->getConsumerMember()Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean$ConsumerMemberBean;

    move-result-object v0

    invoke-virtual {v0}, Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean$ConsumerMemberBean;->getLevel()I

    move-result v0

    if-nez v0, :cond_42

    .line 4
    invoke-virtual {p0}, Ln/FK;->getBinding()Landroidx/viewbinding/ViewBinding;

    move-result-object p1

    check-cast p1, Ltop/acmb/aton/apwrxt/databinding/FragmentVipBinding;

    iget-object p1, p1, Ltop/acmb/aton/apwrxt/databinding/FragmentVipBinding;->a0ES:Landroid/widget/TextView;

    const-string v0, "\u60a8\u5f53\u524d\u8fd8\u4e0d\u662f\u4f1a\u5458"

    invoke-virtual {p1, v0}, Landroid/widget/TextView;->setText(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V

    goto :goto_73

    .line 5
    :cond_42
    invoke-virtual {p0}, Ln/FK;->getBinding()Landroidx/viewbinding/ViewBinding;

    move-result-object v0

    check-cast v0, Ltop/acmb/aton/apwrxt/databinding/FragmentVipBinding;

    iget-object v0, v0, Ltop/acmb/aton/apwrxt/databinding/FragmentVipBinding;->a0ES:Landroid/widget/TextView;

    new-instance v1, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    invoke-direct {v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>()V

    const-string v2, "\u4f1a\u5458\u5c06\u4e8e"

    invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    invoke-virtual {p1}, Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/ConsumerBean;->getMember()Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean;

    move-result-object p1

    invoke-virtual {p1}, Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean;->getConsumerMember()Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean$ConsumerMemberBean;

    move-result-object p1

    invoke-virtual {p1}, Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean$ConsumerMemberBean;->getFinalTime()Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean$ConsumerMemberBean$FinalTimeBeanX;

    move-result-object p1

    invoke-virtual {p1}, Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean$ConsumerMemberBean$FinalTimeBeanX;->getLeftDay()I

    move-result p1

    invoke-virtual {v1, p1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    const-string p1, "\u5929\u540e\u5230\u671f"

    invoke-virtual {v1, p1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    invoke-virtual {v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object p1

    invoke-virtual {v0, p1}, Landroid/widget/TextView;->setText(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V

    :goto_73
    return-void
.end method


I think I should modify the getMember, getConsumerMember, and getLevel methods at the same time, but the first two accept a member variable, and I don't know how to modify it.
# classes2.dex

.class public Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean;
.super Ljava/lang/Object;
.source "MemberBean.java"

# interfaces
.implements Ljava/io/Serializable;


# annotations
.annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/MemberClasses;
    value = {
        Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean$ConsumerMemberBean;,
        Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean$CreatorMemberBean;
    }
.end annotation


# instance fields
.field private consumerMember:Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean$ConsumerMemberBean;

.field private createBoy:Z

.field private creatorMember:Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean$CreatorMemberBean;


# direct methods
.method public constructor <init>()V
    .registers 1

    .line 1
    invoke-direct {p0}, Ljava/lang/Object;-><init>()V

    return-void
.end method


# virtual methods
.method public getConsumerMember()Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean$ConsumerMemberBean;
    .registers 2

    .line 1
    iget-object v0, p0, Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean;->consumerMember:Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean$ConsumerMemberBean;

    return-object v0
.end method

.method public getCreatorMember()Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean$CreatorMemberBean;
    .registers 2

    .line 1
    iget-object v0, p0, Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean;->creatorMember:Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean$CreatorMemberBean;

    return-object v0
.end method

.method public isCreateBoy()Z
    .registers 2

    .line 1
    iget-boolean v0, p0, Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean;->createBoy:Z

    return v0
.end method

.method public setConsumerMember(Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean$ConsumerMemberBean;)V
    .registers 2

    .line 1
    iput-object p1, p0, Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean;->consumerMember:Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean$ConsumerMemberBean;

    return-void
.end method

.method public setCreateBoy(Z)V
    .registers 3

    const/4 p1, 0x1

    iput-boolean p1, p0, Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean;->createBoy:Z

    return-void
.end method

.method public setCreatorMember(Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean$CreatorMemberBean;)V
    .registers 2

    .line 1
    iput-object p1, p0, Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean;->creatorMember:Lshop/ewcpx/xjnmgu/bvxddr/bean/login/MemberBean$CreatorMemberBean;

    return-void
.end method

i have no idea
sorry for my english
i use google translate
I once if-nez v0, :cond_42 assigned the value of v0 to 1. When I compiled it, it crashed on a specific page. I think it detected my memberlevel and I was still an ordinary user. Even after I deleted the killprocess function, it also crashed.
It's hard for me to express my problem accurately
I successfully changed the getNickname part to what I want, it's very simple:>
btw please forgive me if this is a stupid question, I have never learned Android development or Java, I will learn slowly, and I also want to practice it as soon as possible

First, you should decompile the app using jadx & then read the decompiled code.
It should be easier, since this app is not obfuscated.
After you found the target class, method & line you need to tamper, you can mess up with it on smali.
First step is to understand the code and you should do it with jadx as it'll be way faster than reading the smali directly.
You're forced to read smali when jadx fails to decompile classes & methods you're interested in. In that case, you can even use JEB as it successfully decompiles most of the stuff, but it's pay-walled.

If you want to learn smali, the only way to it is this process:-

Coding your own app
Compile it with obfuscation turned off
Decompiling it and try to read both through jadx & smali.
Bring minor changes to code, compile, decompile, and compare to find out how it changed in smali level.
Repeat, and you'll slowly start to understand loops, try catch statements, how boolean & integers are handled, how string is manipulated, how resources are fetch from address, etc.


Reverse engineering a binary, requires knowledge of how exactly that particular type of binary was forward engineered.
If you don't exactly know how it is forward engineered, you won't be able to comprehend lot of technical aspect of decompiled code, as you don't know how it functions and why exactly in that way.
It's like trying to learn a language by reading one of the books written on it. It'll look gibberish to you.
If there's no guide to learn that language, then the best way to learn it is by observing people communicating in it. You'll learn what certain objects are called. You'll try to imitate the words and get live feedback from people who are speaking it.

So, my advice will be to first make android apps, learn basic programming, then try to reverse engineer the apps you made. It'll help you progress way faster.
